# Adding values corresponding to matched column items

Tags: r

I have two sample datasets which are as follows:

```
structure(list(CellType = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("CellA", "CellB", "CellC", "CellD"), class = "factor"), 
    Gene1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, NA, NA), Gene2 = c(0.1, 
    0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2), Gene3 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

And here is the second one:

```
structure(list(CellType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("CellD", 
"CellX", "CellY", "CellZ"), class = "factor"), Gene1 = c(10L, 
20L, 20L, 30L, 10L), Gene2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5), Gene3 = c(0.1, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I would like to add items in 'Gene 1' column that match in 'Cell Type' column from the second data frame to the first one. In this case, only two cell type items match which are 'CellD'. Is there a way for me to add the corresponding values of '10' and '20' from the Gene 1 column of my second dataframe into my 'NA' fields in dataframe # 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Adam, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you explain why there are multiple row of `CellD` that are not uniquely identified and how they relate between tables? That will help us craft a more robust solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case they are sorted `pmatch` could be used. And you really only want to use `CellType` for matching.

```
i <- pmatch(x$CellType, y$CellType)
j <- !is.na(i)
x$Gene1[j] <- y$Gene1[i[j]]
#  CellType Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
#1    CellA   0.1   0.1   0.1
#2    CellB   0.2   0.2   0.2
#3    CellC   0.1   0.1   0.1
#4    CellC   0.3   0.3   0.3
#5    CellA   0.5   0.5   0.5
#6    CellD  10.0   0.2   0.5
#7    CellD  20.0   0.2   0.5
```

Comment: @ GKi Quick follow-up question: Is it possible to apply this code if I had text characters instead of numbers in Gene1 column?

Comment: `pmatch` is actually converting to character vectors. So it should be possible to apply this code to characters.